# Link to another page, execute function, then jump to anchor

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, anchor

I have two pages.  The first has a [slideshow](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/fadeinslideshow.htm) that allows me to add links for each slide.  The second page has numerous expanding div's that are expandable/collapsible onclick using this show/hide function:

```
 function showtxt(divID) {
   var item = document.getElementById(divID);
   if (item) {
     item.className=(item.className=='hidetxt')?'showtxt':'hidetxt';
   }
 }
```

Then each expanding/collapsing div on that page has its own function to call it when clicked:

```
function ANCHORbutton() { 
  var img = document.getElementById('expANCHORbutton').src;
  if (img.indexOf('plus.png')!=-1) { 
    document.getElementById('expANCHORbutton').src  = 'minus.png'; 
  }
  else { 
    document.getElementById('expANCHORbutton').src = 'plus.png'; 
  } 
}
```

What I'd like to do, if possible, is link each slide from that slideshow to the second page, expand the corresponding div, and then jump down the page to the specified anchor.

If I didn't have everything collapsed, it'd be a simple `href="http://domain.com/page2.html#ANCHOR"`, but I'm struggling with how to expand the appropriate section before jumping to my anchor.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you visit the [help] you can see we like to see some code in action. For sure some HTML would be useful.

Comment: You can still use the page2.html#ANCHOR - in your code add the test for location.hash to see which div to expand. For example `if (location.hash) showtxt(location.hash.substring(1))`

Comment: Thanks, @mplungjan.  So I'd link to the second page and anchor normally, then location.hash would collect the specified anchor after the hashtag and then I'd have to run my function and expand the specified div associated with the value collected from using location.hash and finally run another function to jump to that id?  I'm going to have to come back tomorrow night to finish adding all of my code.

Comment: The #divId should jump to the ID automatically assuming it is unique. Then the function could expand it. No need to jump programatically

Comment: The problem is that with all the div's collapsed, everything on the page can be seen (no scrolling), so it doesn't jump to it unless the div is already expanded.

Comment: An additional problem is that if the div is hidden, the hash does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: Collapsed divs all show so no need for browser to scroll
Problem 2: Hidden divs are not being scrolled to since they are hidden.

Solution could be this at the bottom of the page (onload does not trigger on reload on some browsers)

```
<script>
var hash = location.hash;
if (hash) {
  var divID = hash.substring(1); // remove the #
  showtxt(divID);
  document.getElementById(divID).scrollIntoView();
}
</script>
</body>
```

Update to add 100px:

```
var hash = location.hash;
if (hash) {
  var divID = hash.substring(1); // remove the #
  showtxt(divID);
  var div = document.getElementById(divID); 
  div.scrollIntoView(); 
  div.style.top=(parseInt(div.style.top,10)+100)+"px"; 
}
```

Comment: You solved my problem as stated perfectly – thank you!  However, what I didn't realize is that my fixed header/nav covers the heading tag and the first part of the div.  The script scrolls the anchor to the top of the page, but the first ≈100px of the page is covered by the fixed header.  Is there a way I can modify .scrollIntoView() to offset from the top of the page 100px?

Comment: You could try `var div = document.getElementById(divID); div.scrollIntoView(); div.style.top=(parseInt(div.style.top,10)+100)+"px";`

Comment: Unless I'm doing something wrong, that didn't work:  `<script> var hash = location.hash; if (hash) { var divID = hash.substring(1); showtxt(divID);
 document.getElementById(divID); div.scrollIntoView(); 
 div.style.top=(parseInt(div.style.top,10)+100)+"px"; } </script>`

Comment: You did, `showtxt(divID); document.getElementById(divID);` should be `showtxt(divID); var div = document.getElementById(divID);` - see update

Comment: Here's what I'm using now, but it's still not working:  `<script> var hash = location.hash; if (hash) { var divID = hash.substring(1); showtxt(divID);
var div = document.getElementById(divID); div.scrollIntoView(); div.style.top=(parseInt(div.style.top,10)+100)+"px"; } </script>`

Comment: I'll look later. Can you perhaps send me the Url? My details are in my profile